# to start and end a fast

Tags: word-usage

When we keep a fast, we end eating at a particular time thus we say:

> I started my fast at 05:00 a.m.

When we eat to end the fast what should we say:

> to open the fast
>
> to end the fast
>
> to finish the fast

Actually I've heard it in a video that the speaker used the word 'open fast' that was quite strange for me. I don't think if we *open* the fast. When we eat in the evening after a particular time of fasting, we eat so that the act 'fasting' ends. The following source also says so.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasting

Can we say:

> I opened my fast.

or

> I ended my fast.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia link you provided, says

> Each day, the fast **begins** at dawn and **ends** at sunset.

It is completely natural to use "begin" and "end".

> The meal eaten to **end** the fast is known as iftar. - [Wikipedia (Fasting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasting_in_Islam)

It is even more common to use the word "break". J.R., in the comments section, added the link to an Ngram which shows the uses of different verbs.

> The predawn meal is referred to as suhur, and the nightly feast that **breaks** the **fast** is called iftar. - [Wikipedia (Ramadan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan)
>
> At the end of each day, we **break** the **fast** with a light meal called an iftar following the evening call to prayer. - [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2019/05/09/enes-kanter-when-ramadan-nba-playoffs-collide-my-faith-is-my-strength/)
>
> The congressional Iftar marked a rare opportunity for the handful of Muslim members in Congress to open up about their faith and **break fast** in the holy month of Ramadan with their colleagues on Capitol Hill at a time when they are routinely vilified on the right. - [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/may/21/muslim-members-congress-ramadan-iftar-capitol-hill)

I haven't heard the use of "open" when referring to breaking a fast though.

[image]

Comment: One other possible alternative (depending on the sentence) is _finished fasting_. By the way, out of curiosity, I looked at an Ngram, and, indeed, as you say, [_break_ was the most commonly used verb](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broke+my+fast%2Cended+my+fast%2Cfinished+fasting%2Cbreak+a+fast%2Cend+a+fast&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15).